# 404 error with restangular

Tags: angularjs

What I'm I doing wrong from the code below. I'm trying to fetch data from an API however I get a 404 not found. the URL if I hit the browser works and it's the correct URL. I have even tried adding n the full url i.e. `http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/campaign/testcamp/` but this still gives me the same 404. **Why?**

I'm using `angularjs` with `restangular`:

```
app.controller("CampaignData" , ['$scope', 'Restangular',
    function($scope, Restangular){        
        Restangular.one('/api/v1/campaign/testcamp/', "").get().then(
            function(campaign) {
                $scope.campaign = campaign;
                console.log(campaign)
            }
        );
}]);
```

Comment: Do you have the route /api/v1/campaign/testcamp/ with the trailing slash?

Comment: @Lauri Elias I'm a newbie are you saying I need to set a route? if your are referring to the url itself it needs the trailing slash without the slash you will get a 404

Comment: Wait a minute, you're getting one item. So where's the id of the item you're requesting?

Comment: sorry the ID is testcamp the last part of the url

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of an empty string you should specify the id of item you want to `GET`, like that:

```
Restangular.one('/api/v1/campaign/testcamp/', "id_of_item")
```

and looking into the query itself it will probably look something like that:

```
Restangular.one('/api/v1/campaign/', "testcamp")
```

If you get still `404` it may simply mean that your server is not configured properly.